# Completely positive matrix with positive eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues

A matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is called completely positive if there exists an entrywise nonnegative matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$ such that $A = BB^{T}$.
All eigenvalues of $A$ are real and nonnegative.

> My question is when will a completely positive matrix have all positive eigenvalues?

The only completely positive matrix I know so far have zero eigenvalues is
\begin{equation}
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
41 & 43 & 80 & 56 & 50 \\
43 & 62 & 89 & 78 & 51 \\
80 & 89 & 162 & 120 & 93 \\
56 & 78 & 120 & 104 & 62 \\
50 & 51 & 93 & 62 & 65
\end{pmatrix} .
\end{equation}
So probably that the case completely positive matrix has zero eigevalues are rare. But I could not find any documment on this.

**Update:** due to @Robert Israel answer.

Usually, we do not know $B$ in general and indeed the composition may not unique. Therefore the condition depends only in $A$ would be easier to verify.
For example with
\begin{equation}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
18 & 9 & 9 \\ 9 & 18 & 9 \\ 9 & 9 & 18
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
there are at least three decompose satisfies $B \geq 0$. In particular
\begin{equation}
B_{1} = \begin{pmatrix}
4 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 4 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 4
\end{pmatrix} , \quad B_{2} = \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 3 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 3 & 0 & 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix} , \quad B_{3} = \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 3 & 0 \\ 3 & 0 & 3 \\ 0 & 3 & 3
\end{pmatrix} .
\end{equation}

Comment: How about examples similar to $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 2 \\ 2 & 2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}^T$?

Comment: Oh I see.. Thanks @Neal! So it seems that the case completely positive matrix has zero eigevalues are not rare

Comment: I think it depends what you mean by "rare". It is not difficult to create examples, but I would not be surprised at all if Robert Israel is correct and the set of such matrices is closed nowhere dense.

Comment: @Neal "rare" means that if I assume the matrices I consider has all positive eigenvalues is not a too restricted assumption. Like as Robert Israel said, if the set of completely positive matrices with 0 as an eigenvalue form a closed nowhere dense set in the completely positive matrices, then consider the class with all positive eigenvalues is not too restricted, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will have all positive eigenvalues iff $0$ is not an eigenvalue, i.e. iff it is nonsingular, and (if $B$ is also $n \times n$) this is equivalent to $B$ being nonsingular.

EDIT: You are right about the completely positive matrices with $0$ as an eigenvalue being "rare": they form a closed nowhere dense set in the completely positive matrices.

EDIT: Closed because determinant is a continuous function, so $\{A: \det(A)=0\}$ is closed.

Nowhere dense: Given $A = BB^T$ where $B$ is $n \times r$, consider $C(t) = [(1-t)B | tI]$ (i.e. the $n \times (r+n)$ matrix constructed by adjoining the columns of $(1-t) B$ and $tI$, where $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix.  Then for $0 \le t \le 1$, $A(t) = C(t) C(t)^T$ is a completely positive matrix; $A(0) = A$ and $A(1) = I$.  Now $\det A(t)$ is a polynomial in $t$ and not identically $0$, so it is nonzero for almost all $t$.  In particular, there are nonsingular completely positive matrices $A(t)$ arbitrarily close to $A$.

Comment: thanks for your point. However it seems not very useful since first, usually, we don't know $B$. And second, the decomposition may not unique therefore in my opinion it would be much more difficult to verify if you put some condition on $B$. I will modify my post

Comment: If you want to test whether a particular $A$ is nonsingular, you can just take the determinant.

Comment: The hard part, AFAIK, it to find an entrywise nonnegative $B$ for a given $A$.  For this I would try numerical optimization.

Comment: Yes indeed I found some algorithm to find $B$, however it require that $A$ is nonsingular. That's the reason why I asked if this situation usually happen

Comment: "they form a closed nowhere dense set in the completely positive matrices" this a positive result for me. But could you please show me the reference about it or is it a new result?

Answer (score 3):

A nice result on the subject is given in:

*Kogan, Natalia; Berman, Abraham*, [**Characterization of completely positive graphs**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(93)90374-3), Discrete Math. 114, No. 1-3, 297-304 (1993). [ZBL0783.05071](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0783.05071).

Comment: thank you! I will have a look on that